# Concurrent database access on shared network drive

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, entity

I'm part of a small team that currently uses an Access database for scheduling a larger team's availability.  This has presented some issues with corruption of the Access database.  Additionally, I want to implement additional functionality over time.

I've set out to create an application for the 4-5 of us to use that will solve the concurrent database issue, as well as give the team more functionality.

Since this is a shared network drive, I won't have access to SQL Server (from my guess).  I thought maybe a web service would be the way to go, but I don't really want to front the bill for this.  Additionally, when I eventually leave the team I don't want to maintain this.

Some ideas I've come up with is an application written in C# that acts as the front-end with SQLite embedded as the back-end.  However, I've spent days trying to get the Entity Framework to work with SQLite and am at the point of giving up.

I'm trying to decide what else I can do to solve this issue.  Is there another technology I can use?

Comment: Seems like you're doing a lot of work to reinvent SQL Server.

Comment: I would love to use SQL Server.  Am I misunderstanding this that if the network shared drive is running a version of Windows Server then it should have SQL Server installed that I should be able to use?

Comment: almost all the concerns you have are not a problem. Time to throw away the book you were reading and get a new one.

Comment: @Steve, please elaborate on which concern.

Comment: "multiple users can result in corruption of database" - only happens if multiple users using the same database file 
"Since this is a shared network drive, I won't have access to SQL Server" - why not?
"web service would be the way to go, but I don't really want to front the bill for this" - can be done in 1 day if you are not building UI
"Some ideas I've come up with is an application written in C# that acts as the front-end with SQLite embedded as the back-end" you are basically trying to reinvent web server and Sql server's concurrency model

Comment: @Steve, we're already dealing with the corruption of an Access database; hence us looking into alternatives.  And when I mean "foot the bill", I mean paying for running the server. I am a pilot in the military and this is a side-project for me to make our lives easier since we don't really have the tools needed to do our jobs efficiently. I will look into SQL Server on the network drive.  These are government computers so a lot of rights/privileges are locked down.

Comment: @keelerjr12 if my guess is right then you are dealing with corruption because you are running multiple instances of the application which uses the same database file. In such case you are almost guarantee to have corruption. Get one computer to run as server and use connection string to connect. problem solved. If money is really a problem then install Linux on the machine and use MySQL + .net core. Code everything in c# and run it free of charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said, it sounds like you try to reinvent the DMBS wheel.

If you have a Database that multiple clients can use at the same time, "sharing a access file on a network share" will simply not cut it. You need a proper DBMS. You have simply outgrown the scale Access was designed for. propably even the scale it was intended for.

You said cost might be an issue, but it is not really: There are dozens of DBMS out there, with a number being Freeware. MySQL is a shining example of a free DBMS. Conver that whole Access thing into a MySQL Database. Write a frontend for the MySQL Database. Done.

If you already have a computer providing the share across the network, that same computer can provide the MySQL Server. Setting up a DBMS with 1+ instances can be a bit more involved then just enabling a share, but not much more then programming a WebService.

Comment: Completely agree with you.  However, these are government computers and I can't necessarily just stall MySQL or SQL Server willy-nilly.  I assume if it's already installed then I should be able to create a new database and tables from my application.

Comment: If you can not install and run a MySQL Server you surely can not run a WebService on that computer either. And it is not like those Servers are even demanding regarding rights. I once did some PHP learning with nothing but limited Userrights, 300 MiB Contingent and the Portable version of XAMPP (the M stands for MySQL). If you are not allowed to run software like MySQL, running custom software would be a worse security risk.

Comment: We are not allowed to use thumb drives, but I can put a simple .exe on a CD and copy it to the network drive to then run.  However, unless you're a comm guy, no one has privileges to install any software (e.g. chrome, firefox, etc.).  You'd be amazed how technology-inhibited the government is in some areas.

Comment: So if I host the webservice using ASP.NET with MSSQL elsewhere, I should be able to use a simple WPF UI to access it and do what I need to do.

Comment: Now you are talking about hosting the WebService/MSSQL database on another computer altogether? I am afraid I do not get what your actuall limits of skill, hardware and money are.

Comment: I cannot host it on the shared drive or another computer on the network because they are all government computers. I am in the military and a pilot; not as a software engineer so my access is severely limited. I don’t have the privileges to be able to do a lot. The computers are pretty locked down to running various applications like Outlook, IE, Excel, etc. These are all installed for us, we don’t even have privileges to install these. I basically only have the ability to run a UI client.

Comment: Registering a port to listen on is not generally something that requires adminsitrative rights. As I said, I got a portable mySQL Server running on basic user rights. And portable Software needs no installation (originally they are designed to be copied to a USB stick like medium, but I just used it in anotehr way). If you can get it hosted on a computer in the internet - and you actually have free access to the internet - this might be the safest solution. Of course depending on the Network Admin(s) and their rules, even running the UI client might be too much already.